# Update the Google Search Console API discovery document

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-api-client

We got an email regarding updating discovery document.

**Starting November 1, 2021, projects which have not updated their discovery document will no longer be supported and will stop working.**

We are using [external API library: googleapis/google-api-php-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client), for Webmasters API.

Currently I'm using the below API call.

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName(xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx);
$client->setAuthConfig(xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx);
$scopesArray = array(
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters'
  );
$client->setScopes($scopesArray);
...................................................
.....................................................

$googlewebmasterssearchsnalyticsobject = new \Google_Service_Webmasters_SearchAnalyticsQueryRequest();
$googlewebmasterssearchsnalyticsobject->setStartDate('1970-01-01');
$endDate = gmdate('Y-m-d');
$googlewebmasterssearchsnalyticsobject->setEndDate($endDate);
$googlewebmasterssearchsnalyticsobject->setDimensions(['page', 'date']);
$googlewebmasterssearchsnalyticsobject->setSearchType('web');
..................................................................
```

What should I update in the above API call?

Comment: Of all the service providers I've ever integrated with (which are many), none have been so needlessly complex than that of Google.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't directly using the discovery document the Client library does for you. Any issues should have been addressed in that library already.

If you are worried you should cross post this issue over on their [issue forum](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/issues).  if there is an issue its something that should be fixed in the library

I can see this question was cross posed to [Update the Google Search Console API discovery document #2149](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/issues/2149)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Google's client library, you must update the *discovery doc*

**From:** `https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/webmasters/v3/rest`
**To:** `https://searchconsole.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest`

In my case, I was using Google's JavaScript client library, and was not providing the ***discoveryDocs*** parameter. I needed to replace instances of `webmaster / v3` to `searchconsole / v1`, as shown below.

**From:**

```js
gapi.client.load('webmasters', 'v3').then(function(){
```

**To:**

```js
gapi.client.load('searchconsole', 'v1').then(function(){
```